# $A\leq_m B$ and $B\in\Pi_n\implies A\in \Pi_n$

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, recursion, computability

Suppose $A\leq_m B$ and $B$ is, say, $\Pi_2$. I don't understand this proof of the fact that $A$ is $\Pi_2$:

Assume $z\in B\iff \forall y_1\exists y_2 R(z,y_1,y_2)$ where $R$ is computable. If $A\leq_m B$ via $f$, then $$x\in A\iff f(x)\in B \iff \forall y_1\exists y_2 R(f(x),y_1,y_2).$$

Why does the above prove that $A$ is $\Pi_2$? $A$ being $\Pi_2$ amounts to saying that $$x\in A\iff \forall y_1\exists y_2 T(x,y_1,y_2)$$
for some computable $T$. But the above only shows that $$x\in A\iff \forall y_1\exists y_2 T(f(x),y_1,y_2)$$
for some computable $T$ and some computable total function $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that we can "substitute $f$ in" since $f$ itself is total computable: given a computable relation $R$ and a total computable function $f$, the relation $$T(a,b,c):= R(f(a),b,c)$$ is again total computable.

Comment: I thought about this, but a relation is officially a set. How would you write the set $T$ in terms of the set $R$ and the function $f$?

Comment: @user634426 It's just $T=\{(a,b,c): (f(a),b,c)\in R\}$. Nothing messy going on.

Comment: Oh, thanks. If $f$ wasn't total, nothing would break, I guess? $T$ would still be computable (and there's no requirement in the definition of $\Sigma_2$ sets that $T$ be total).

Comment: @user634426 You need $f$ to be total in order for this to make sense: if $f(a)$ isn't defined, what does "$(f(a),b,c)\in R$" mean?